# How can I print the contents of a org.squeryl.dsl.Group?

Tags: scala, squeryl

Using Squeryl ORM and Scala. For the first time I did a JOIN statement that used grouping. Admittedly, I can't figure out how to start iterating through the contents.

Here's the JOIN:

```
join(DB.jobs, DB.users.leftOuter, DB.clients.leftOuter, DB.projects.leftOuter)((j,u,c,p) =>
      where((j.teamId === teamId)
        and (j.startTime > yesterdayBegin))
      groupBy(j.userId)
      on(j.userId === u.map(_.id), j.clientId === c.map(_.id), j.projectId === p.map(_.id)))
```

How do I print out its contents?

I tried:

```
Job.teamTimeline( teamId(request) ).map{ user => Map(
        "name" -> user._1.map(_.name).getOrElse("Pending")
      )}
```

But got the compiler error:

```
value _1 is not a member of org.squeryl.dsl.Group[Option[org.squeryl.PrimitiveTypeMode.LongType]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Max the great was able to help out on the mailing list. I almost had the syntax right.

**His response:**

replace :

```
groupBy(j.userId)
```

by:

```
groupBy(j.userId, j.name)
```

then :

```
timelineLookup.map{ group => Map(

        "name" -> group.key._2.getOrElse("Pending")

      )}
```

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/squeryl/sJ05He-4F3I